# konva keep one layer always fixed while zoom on stage

Tags: angular, konvajs, konva

I am creating an angular application and using KonvaJS to draw all my shapes on Canvas. In this application, I have created three layers. Out of which one layer will be used to draw the axis (x and y) on canvas and other layers will be used to draw shapes.

I am drawing the x and y axes using the Konva line. Now when I zoom in to the stage, I can see after a certain zoom, the stroke width of the lines increases.

I would like to exclude my axisLayer from this zoom so that it always shows the same axis lines despite of any zoom level.

Answer (score 0):

In that use case, it is better not to apply zoom/scale to the whole stage. Instead, apply scale only to layers/groups that you want to zoom. On other containers, you may need to recalculate positions of elements to match new zoom.